# Inpute missing value based on identifier

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation

I like to fill in missing values for some variable based on its value paired with a matching index. Example (First col is the index; second col is the values).

`mat <- cbind(c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4), c(4.3, NA, 2.4, NA, 3.8, NA, 1.2, NA, NA))`

`newmat <- cbind(c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4), c(4.3, 4.3, 2.4, 2.4, 3.8, 3.8, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2))`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `fill`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mat %>% 
  as_tibble %>% 
  group_by(V1) %>% 
  fill(V2, .direction = 'updown')
```

Comment: Thanks!! One addition, to make sure it fills above and below, I added %>% arrange(V2). Otherwise, works great!

Comment: @DonZhang you can use `fill(V2, .direction = 'updown')`

Comment: oh yea, thanks! didn't know that!